# How to fix error of "Object connection lost from its client" in VBscript"?

Tags: vbscript

my code where I try to login into the website automatically. But it keeps on throwing

> The object is lost connection from its client

```
Dim IE
set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = true

Call IE.navigate("http://finrpa:8080/controlroom/")

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop

IE.Document.all.username-inputEl.Value = "parthiban.nadar@thirdware.com"
IE.Document.all.password-inputEl.Value = "Thirdw@re1"

Call IE.Document.all.gaia_loginform.submit

Set IE = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you try https instead of http?

Comment: I do hope that's not your actual login username and password.........

Answer (score 0):

What line the exception is thrown?
I see at least one problem with the script. Because the control names contain dashes, they should be strings. So, instead of

```
IE.Document.all.username-inputEl.Value = "parthiban.nadar@thirdware.com"
IE.Document.all.password-inputEl.Value = "Thirdw@re1"
```

should be

```
IE.Document.getElementById("username-inputEl").Value = "parthiban.nadar@thirdware.com"
IE.Document.getElementById("password-inputEl").Value = "Thirdw@re1"
```

Comment: I tried your code, its not working and throwing the same error on the 8 th line of the code.

Comment: Please confirm that line 8 is "WScript.Sleep 10". How do you run you script? Do you execute "cscript  script_name.vbs" or some other way?